# Set font size for multi line tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I try to set the font size for a tikz node that contains a line break (`"\\ "`) the font size is only set for the first line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \node[align=left] at (0,0) {\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont first line\\ second line};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

How can I set the font size for the whole node?

Comment: Thanks for this question. I made a feature out of this bug. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `font=\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont` in the node options.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{fontspec} %commented because it's not really relevant
%\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \node[align=left,font=\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont] at (0,0) {first line\\ second line};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(`\fontsize{size}{baselineskip}`)